# How do I return a Hashmap inside a JSONArray response?

Tags: android

I want to access **email** and **phone** in HashMap **from outside** of the **JSONArray Response**. How can I do this?

I tried making globale variables and assign values to them. It didn't worked.

```
    JsonArrayRequest request1 = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();
                            map.put("email", obj.getString("email"));
                            map.put("phone", obj.getString("phone"));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error"+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Just move `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();` out of `JsonArrayRequest`

Comment: @РасулA-ев **Variable 'map' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final** this error is shown

Comment: refer my answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/50791319/8101634

Answer (score 0):

Declare `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();` at top level in your class

And use it in your `JsonArrayRequest`

```
@Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);                              
                            map.put("email", obj.getString("email"));
                            map.put("phone", obj.getString("phone"));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: I did it. But null values are returned

Comment: Values are not null inside JSONArrayRequest